# No errors can't return data from map function?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

In the browser console I get the object. But when I try and return just the text, link, title nothing returns. I get the object in the console, but when I try and add .text or .link the page shows blank. The console shows no errors.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Navigation extends Component {

  getLinks = (object) => {
  Object.keys(object).map((property, i) => {
      const { text, title } = object[property][i];
      console.log(object[property][i])
      return  (
        <ul>{title}
        <li>{text}</li>
        </ul>
      )
    });


}
  render() {


    let { items } = this.props;
    return (

      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.getLinks(items)}
        </ul>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

JSON

```
const navigation = {
  pageInfo: [
  {title: "A title"},
  {text: "item 1", link: "https://google.com"},
  {text: " item 2", link: "https://googleconquestio.com"}
  ],
  pageInfo2: [
  {title: "A title"},
  {text: "item 1", link: "https://google.com"},
  {text: "item 2", link: "https://googleconquestio.com"}
  ],
  pageInfo3: [
  {title: "Applications"},
  {text: "application item 1", link: "https://google.com"},
  {text: "application item 2", link: "https://googleconquestio.com"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Interesting downvote with no answer.

Comment: A couple things are happening. First you are not returning the newly created array that map returns. Second you will also need to loop through each of your keys in your navigation object since they are arrays. You are trying to grab {title, text} from object[property][i], but that won't work since title is at index 0 and text is at index 1. I would recommend re-structuring your data

Comment: put a return infront of Object.keys....

Comment: Good point. I've changed my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things are happening. First you are not returning the newly created array that map returns. Second you will also need to loop through each of your keys in your navigation object since they are arrays. You are trying to grab {title, text} from object[property][i], but that won't work since title is at index 0 and text is at index 1. I would recommend re-structuring your data.

You could do something like this:

```
const navigation = [
    {
        title: 'Title 1',
        text: [
            { 
                name: 'item 1',
            },
            {
                name: 'item 2',
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        title: 'Title 2',
        text: [
            { 
                name: 'item 1',
            },
            {
                name: 'item 2',
            }
        ],
    }
];

return navigation.map(obj => {

    let listElements = obj.text.map((li, c) => {
        return (
            <li key={c}>{li.name}</li>
        );
    });
    return (
        <ul>
            {obj.title}
            {listElements}
        </ul>
    );
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. Console returns data, but nothing in the page. Page renders, but no data. https://gist.github.com/thebetterjort/aaf0eeba71dd1649c4d137a3a54492dc

Comment: you need to return the `navigation.map`

Comment: Thank you for this well needed lesson.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a return in the arrow function if you use braces that way: 
Here is an example JSBin: https://jsbin.com/mijuh/2/edit?js,console

```
  getLinks = (object) => {
   return Object.keys(object).map((property, i) => {
      const { text, title } = object[property][i];
      console.log(object[property][i])
      return  (
        <ul>{title}
        <li>{text}</li>
        </ul>
      )
    });
```

Comment: look @realseanp comment. The reason why this isn't working is because of the use of arrays and the index is off.